# Deleting cell leads to a crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So my `numberOfRowsInSection` is:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let delegate = delegate else { return 0 }
    return delegate?.comments.count + 1
}
```

I added one more to compensate for the "load more" which is on top of the table view (in this case, it's row 0).

Here's the thing: when I want to remove that cell "load more" after fetching the max amount of posts, it gives me an error:

```
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (12) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

So here's the function that causes the error:

```
func loadMore() {
    // loadMoreComments(completion:) inserts the new comment objects inside
    // the data source in the beginning of the list.
    delegate?.loadMoreComments(completion: { (isEndOfPosts, newCommentCount, comments) in
        self.didReachEndOfPosts = isEndOfPosts
        if isEndOfPosts {
            // indexPaths just returns [[0,1]], or, just one row.
            let indexPaths = self.createIndexPathsForNoMorePosts(newCommentCount: newCommentCount)
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            // error happens here.
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()

            // assume only one post comes in, and that's the last one.
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is this: once i get the last post, remove the "load more" cell, and insert the last few posts, replacing the 0 row with the first of the last few posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notify your tableView's datasource about cell count change. Create a class variable, something like

```
var shouldShowLoadMoreCell = true
```

and than modify `numberOfRowsInSection` method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   guard let delegate = delegate else { return 0 }
   if shouldShowLoadMoreCell {
       return delegate?.comments.count + 1
   } else {
       return delegate?.comments.count
   }
}
```

finally, set this flag when needed

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
shouldShowLoadMoreCell = false
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would `beginUpdates/endUpdates` call `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: Sure, you can check this by placing there a breakpoint or putting some `print()` function

Comment: Great! This definitely worked. I didn't have any idea that `begin/endUpdate` actually worked the similarly to `reloadData`.